# ArrayAdapter retains views on Android 4.3

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

This only happens on Android 4.3, physical device and virtual emulator.

I have a list view that I fill with a custom adapter

https://github.com/markholland/ocw-android/blob/development/src/org/osuosl/ocw/Schedule.java#L1509

When I change screens and fill the adapter again but with for example only one item, this means that the screen won't be filled with items, the items from the previous screen are still present. The single item is there and clickable but all the leftover items aren't clickable.

If I then pause the app or perform a screen orientation switch, the view loads properly with just one item.

Comment: From what I see in these almost 2000 lines of code: Your adapter is a member variable. Try clearing it on orientation-change or recreate it.